# Triggers to connect multiple tables

Tags: mysql, triggers

So I have two tables in my database: 'test1' and 'cities'. I have the following columns in test1: 'Origin', 'OriginIndex' (I'm only mentioning the relevant ones), and in cities: 'city', 'value' (again, relevant ones only). The 'cities' table has 5000 cities in the 'city' column and has double values (like 0.990, 0.345, 0.457, 1.566) in the 'value' column corresponding to each city (like London, Paris, etc).

So let's say that a user gives an input of 'London' into the 'Origin' column of 'test1' table.  In the 'cities' table, London 'city' has a 'value' of 1.555. Now, I am trying to fire a trigger in phpmyadmin which would check if 'Origin' = 'city' and if yes, the corresponding 'value' will be stored in the 'OriginIndex' after insertion of 'London'. I have created my trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t1
AFTER INSERT ON test1 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE test1 a, cities b SET a.OriginIndex = b.value WHERE a.Origin = b.city;
END
```

However, this is not storing the 'value' into the 'OriginIndex' every time I give inputs in 'Origin' column of 'test1' table on my php website (localhost). Can anybody figure out the error? Any advice or hint would be highly appreciated! =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. MySql doesn't allow to make changes within a trigger code to the same table on which you have that trigger
2. You can overcome this limitation by changing a column value of a row being inserted using `BEFORE` event rather than `AFTER`.
3. Now to address column values of a row being inserted in MySql you need to use `NEW` keyword.

That being said your trigger should look like

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_test1_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON test1 
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.originindex = 
     (
       SELECT value 
         FROM cities 
        WHERE city = NEW.origin
     );
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3ef9/1)** demo

Comment: I have another question. I created the trigger like you did and it worked. However, I am trying to multiply two values, i.e., originindex and destinationindex.

Comment: In what table `destinationindex` index is stored and what data type is it? Show a couple of rows of sample data.

Comment: Here's the link to that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137792/triggers-to-multiply-trigger-based-columns-in-mysql