# triggers to multiply 'trigger-based columns' in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, multiplication

I have asked this question before and I want to elaborate it.

[Triggers to connect multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877250/triggers-to-connect-multiple-tables)

I have the following trigger (kind of like the one I asked before):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_test1
BEFORE INSERT ON test1 
FOR EACH ROW 
  SET NEW.OriginIndex = (SELECT index1 FROM cities WHERE city = NEW.Origin),
    NEW.DestinationIndex = (SELECT index1 FROM cities WHERE city =NEW.Destination);
```

This part works well. Now I want to multiply OriginIndex and DestinationIndex and store it in another column (let's say 'Multiplication').

I did this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_test1
BEFORE INSERT ON test1 
FOR EACH ROW 
  SET NEW.OriginIndex = (SELECT index1 FROM cities WHERE city = NEW.Origin),
    NEW.DestinationIndex = (SELECT index1 FROM cities WHERE city =NEW.Destination),
        NEW.Multiplication = (SELECT NEW.OriginIndex*NEW.DestinationIndex);
```

This gives an error 'This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table''.

How am I supposed to approach this problem?

Comment: OriginIndex and DestinationIndex are double (10,4).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_test1
BEFORE INSERT ON test1 
BEGIN
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.OriginIndex = (SELECT index1 FROM cities WHERE city = NEW.Origin);
SET NEW.DestinationIndex = (SELECT index1 FROM cities WHERE city =NEW.Destination);
SET NEW.Multiplication = (NEW.OriginIndex*NEW.DestinationIndex);
END//
```

I hope this help.